# Paperclip link field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a model with an image attribute managed by Paperclip.  Is it possible to have Paperclip populate that attribute based on a URL to a remote location?  Also, does this work with Paperclip's Amazon S3 support?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how you configure paperclip to use s3:  https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Paperclip-with-Amazon-S3

Comment: I asked if paperclip is able to upload a picture to s3 if I only give it a link to the photo. It should be able to download the picture from it's original location and then store it in s3.

Comment: That isn't obvious from what you wrote above, but with that information, you probably want Scenario #1 here:  https://gist.github.com/1112841